# How to fix an Id undefined filter error in MUI DataGrid React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI DataGrid with a singleSelect column, it is displaying and editing data correctly but throws up the following error when I select the column filter menu item:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

I realise from the error when setting up the filter it is looking for the id property from the valueOptions and the value is undefined.

Obviously I am just learning about the DataGrid for the first time. This is what I have tried so far:

```
const { PartGroups, hasPartGroupsUpdate } = useAppSelector((state) => state.partGroups);

const [partGroups, setPartGroups] = useState<{id: number, description: string}[]>([{id: 0, description: '[Blank]'}]);

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: 'PartId', headerName: 'Part Id', width: 70, type: 'number', valueFormatter: ({ value }) => value },
    {
        field: 'PartGroupId',
        headerName: 'Part Group',
        width: 200,
        type: 'singleSelect',
        valueGetter: (params) => params.row.PartGroupId !== undefined && params.row.PartGroupId !== null ? params.row.PartGroupId : 0,
        getOptionValue: (value: any) => value.id,
        getOptionLabel: (value: any) => value.description,
        valueOptions: (params) => partGroups,
        editable: true,
    },
    { field: 'Description', headerName: 'Description', flex: 1, minWidth: 250 },
    {
        field: 'DateLastUpdated',
        headerName: 'Last Updated',
        width: 160,
        valueFormatter: ({ value }) => moment(value).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    },
];

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(PartGroups)
    let newPartGroups:{id: number, description: string}[] = [{id: 0, description: '[Blank]'}];
    const tempPartGroups = PartGroups.map((partGroup: PartGroupExt) => {
        return {id: partGroup.PartGroupId, description: partGroup.PartGroupName}
    })
    newPartGroups = [...newPartGroups, ...tempPartGroups];
    setPartGroups(newPartGroups);
}, [PartGroups])
```

The Part Group does not need to be set and is sometimes null, hence the valueGetter() being used to select the [Blank].

The full error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at getOptionValue (http://localhost:3000/main.ff56c9973bbd0507b366.hot-update.js:163:36)
    at getValueFromValueOptions (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:87101:10)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:86603:94
    at commitHookEffectListMount (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:144267:30)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:145760:17)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:145732:13)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:145722:11)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:145712:7)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:147597:7)
    at flushPassiveEffects (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:147549:18)
```

I'm using server side pagination, sorting and filtering.

1. How do I allow the filter to access the partGroups?
2. Also can I use the valueSetter() to somehow update the data, so that when 0 -> [Blank] is selected it will set the PartGroupId to null.

**[Update]**

I found that if I change properties in partGroups from {id, description} to {value, label} and remove getOptionValue() and getOptionLabel() it works just fine.

However, that is not what I want, how to get this to work with my own properties?

**[Update 2]**
I have put together a [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-forest-28zz89?file=/src/Demo.tsx), however the error is a bit different, it is asking for a key to be set on the filter

**[Update 3]**
Still stuck on this, it may be something small however I have not figured it out.